# how to check if a list[string] is subset of another list[string] in scala

Tags: scala, word-count

I basically have two files input1 and input2 (both are List[string]). I want to check if they are sub-string to one another/identical. So, i have the below

```
Val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName (“check identical”)
Val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val input 1 = sc.textFile(inputFile-L)
Val input 2 = sc.textFile(inputFile-M) 

// split up words
val words1 = input1.flatMap(line=> line.split(""))
Val words2 = input2.flatMap(line=>line.split(""))

// Transform into word and count 
val counts1 = words1.map(word => (word, reducebyKey{case(x,y) => x+y})
val counts2 = words2.map(word => (word, reducebyKey{case(x,y) => x+y})
```

By above, I made sure that word count is same, now how to compare the subset? Any easy approaches to be taken ?

Comment: could you add a data sample and expected result? Not sure what you mean by 'subset'/'sub-string' in this context

Comment: If `(a diff b).isEmpty` then a is a subset of b

Comment: @LuigiPlinge sure. But see how subset and substring are used here as if they where interchangeable. substring requires ordering.

Comment: I don't think that sample code does what you say it does.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
val notInWords1 = words2.filterNot(w => words1.contains(w))
val notInWords2 = words1.filterNot(w => words2.contains(w))

val bothAreEqual = notInWords1.isEmpty && notInWords2.isEmpty

val subset = Option( if(notInWords1.isEmpty && notInWords2.nonEmpty) words2
                else if(notInWords2.isEmpty && notInWords1.nonEmpty) words1)

val oneIsASubsetOfTheOther = subset.isDefined
val words1IsSubsetOfWords2 = subset.getOrElse(false) == words1
val words2IsSubsetOfWords1 = subset.getOrElse(false) == words2
```

Comment: not difference, I'm basically trying to write a function to check if M is a subset of L or not @Mr D

Comment: @pruthvi I added a bunch of things, that should cover what you need I believe

Comment: what is oneIsASubsetOfTheOther used for ?

Comment: To check if either one is a subset of the other (both could be equal or they could be different but not be subsets), I didn't really use it in the code but I thought it'd be a nice addition... I could also have implemented `words1IsSubsetOfWords2` in terms of `oneIsASubsetOfTheOther` but the result would have been the same and I saw no reason to force it to depend on it

Comment: Thank you ! that helps. basically i was not aware of functions like "subset" already exists !

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
words1.foreach(words2.contains)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Scala programming:

```
def hasSequence[A](l1: List[A], l2: List[A]): Boolean =  {
    def matchSeq(l1: List[A], l2: List[A], l2Original: List[A]): Boolean = {
        (l1, l2) match {
           case (_, Nil) => true
           case (Nil, _) => false //short circuit this case if l2.size > l1.size
           case (h1::t1, h2::t2) if h1 == h2 => matchSeq(t1, t2, l2Original)
           case (_::tail1, _) =>matchSeq(tail1, l2Original, l2Original)
        }
     }
  if(l2.isEmpty) false else matchSeq(l1, l2, l2)
}
```